# How to make bold each word in a latex table?

Tags: python, string, latex

The next example is one of many tables I produce with pandas for a report, for which I need to make the header columns bold.
Due to other processing needed for the tables, I can't make it before, meaning that I really need to make the changes in the LateX code.
I get the full table in LateX as a string from python code.

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llrrrrr}
\toprule
{} & {} & {\#d} & {\#i} & {\#l} & {\#s} & {\#o} \\
{Dataset} & {Model} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} \\
\midrule
\multirow[c]{5}{*}{\textit{D (simple)}} & b & 1,026 & 692 & \itshape 31 & 284 & 1,007 \\
 & f & 1,366 & 398 & 49 & 238 & 685 \\
 & f+d & 1,372 & 415 & 46 & 215 & 676 \\
 & f+d+pt & 1,372 & 415 & 46 & 215 & 676 \\
 & f+d+tg & \bfseries 1,732 & \itshape 8 & 82 & 262 & \itshape 352 \\
\multirow[c]{5}{*}{\textit{D (complex)}} & b & 527 & 266 & 228 & 589 & 1,083 \\
 & f & 759 & 153 & 270 & 470 & 893 \\
 & f+d & 749 & 177 & 233 & 456 & 866 \\
 & f+d+pt & 749 & 177 & 233 & 456 & 866 \\
 & f+d+tg & \bfseries 969 & \itshape 33 & \itshape 38 & \itshape 380 & \itshape 451 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Is there a simple way to make the column headers bold? Ie, I'd like to obtain the following output:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llrrrrr}
\toprule
{} & {} & {\textbf{\#d}} & {\textbf{\#i}} & {\textbf{\#l}} & {\textbf{\#s}} & {\textbf{\#o}} \\
{\textbf{Dataset}} & {\textbf{Model}} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} \\
\midrule
\multirow[c]{5}{*}{\textit{D (simple)}} & b & 1,026 & 692 & \itshape 31 & 284 & 1,007 \\
 & f & 1,366 & 398 & 49 & 238 & 685 \\
 & f+d & 1,372 & 415 & 46 & 215 & 676 \\
 & f+d+pt & 1,372 & 415 & 46 & 215 & 676 \\
 & f+d+tg & \bfseries 1,732 & \itshape 8 & 82 & 262 & \itshape 352 \\
\multirow[c]{5}{*}{\textit{D (complex)}} & b & 527 & 266 & 228 & 589 & 1,083 \\
 & f & 759 & 153 & 270 & 470 & 893 \\
 & f+d & 749 & 177 & 233 & 456 & 866 \\
 & f+d+pt & 749 & 177 & 233 & 456 & 866 \\
 & f+d+tg & \bfseries 969 & \itshape 33 & \itshape 38 & \itshape 380 & \itshape 451 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I assume that this can be done with regex but I can't understand it. I'd need to replace every occurrence of `{content}` when `content` is not empty.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you get the whole table as a string or ...?

Comment: Yes, i do get the whole table as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below should give you the desired output. Basically searching for the header section, and then replacing the non-empty brackets with regex. This part can also be done with some for loops but this seems cleaner.

```
1 {    all stuff with 1+ chars except } ->\g<1>  1 }
[\{]            ([^}]+?)                        [\}]
```

```py
import re

new_table = ''
working_on_header = False
for line in old_table.split('\n'):

    if line == '\\toprule':
        working_on_header = True
    elif line == '\\midrule':
        working_on_header = False
    elif working_on_header:
        line = re.sub(r"[\{]([^}]+?)[\}]", r"{\\textbf{\g<1>}}", line)
    new_table += line + '\n'
```

Comment: What if I want to change all words in the header (no need to be enclosed in {}), ie " &  & F-measure & ae \\" --> " &  & \textbf{F-measure} & \textbf{ae} \\"?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use the `tabularray` package. This allows to make all the decisions about formatting at the start of the table, so you'll just have to exchange your previous `tabular` environment with the new settings and don't have to touch the cells themselves. You can even ask latex to do this for you:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularray}[=v2021]
\usepackage{multirow}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\renewenvironment{tabular}[1]{
  \begin{tblr}{
    row{1-2}={font=\bfseries},
    colspec={#1}
  }
}{\end{tblr}}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llrrrrr}
\toprule
{} & {} & {\#d} & {\#i} & {\#l} & {\#s} & {\#o} \\
{Dataset} & {Model} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} \\
\midrule
\multirow[c]{5}{*}{\textit{D (simple)}} & b & 1,026 & 692 & \itshape 31 & 284 & 1,007 \\
 & f & 1,366 & 398 & 49 & 238 & 685 \\
 & f+d & 1,372 & 415 & 46 & 215 & 676 \\
 & f+d+pt & 1,372 & 415 & 46 & 215 & 676 \\
 & f+d+tg & \bfseries 1,732 & \itshape 8 & 82 & 262 & \itshape 352 \\
\multirow[c]{5}{*}{\textit{D (complex)}} & b & 527 & 266 & 228 & 589 & 1,083 \\
 & f & 759 & 153 & 270 & 470 & 893 \\
 & f+d & 749 & 177 & 233 & 456 & 866 \\
 & f+d+pt & 749 & 177 & 233 & 456 & 866 \\
 & f+d+tg & \bfseries 969 & \itshape 33 & \itshape 38 & \itshape 380 & \itshape 451 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm rather limited in my options: the table needs to be produced by pandas.to_latex() so I need the solution to be python code to change LateX and not LateX. Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @MrT77 You don't have to touch the table itself, you can ask latex to do it for you

Comment: How can I make this solution work for my tables that can have 1,2 or 3 rows as header?

Comment: Also, is this solution applicable to longtable or tabularx or xltabular?

Comment: @MrT77 You could set a counter before you include the table which has the number of headers rows.

Comment: @MrT77 With the right redefinitions and the right tabularray libraries, I don't see why this shouldn't work for other environments as well