# `pandas.to_latex` - how to make column names bold

Tags: python, pandas, latex

When I'm using the `pandas.to_latex` function to create latex table, the column names are unfortunately not bold. What can I do to make it bold?

Comment: You could let latex do the job for you, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71473887/2777074

Comment: I want to create latex file automatically from python so I need to do it somehow in this function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

I have been told [on GitHub](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/46790) that this is allready possible with plain pandas but there is some missing documentation, which will be updated soon.

You can use the line below.

```
result = df.style.applymap_index(
    lambda v: "font-weight: bold;", axis="columns"
).to_latex(convert_css=True)
```

**Old answer**

Here is a complete example, this is adapted from the offical [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_latex.html?highlight=to_latex#pandas.DataFrame.to_latex).

There is a keyword to print bold columns `bold_rows=True`. Sadly there isn't a kyword parameter to do the same for the columns. But I can use this to check if my code gives the same result for the column headers.

I use the result of `to_latex()` and split it in three sections. One section is the line with the column names. In this line I use a regular expression to add the  `\text{}`-string. My code works only if you colum names don't have a whitespace.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(name=['Raphael', 'Donatello'],
         mask=['red', 'purple'],
         weapon=['sai', 'bo staff']
        )
)
ans = df.to_latex(bold_rows=True)

split_middle = '\n\midrule\n'
split_top = '\\toprule\n'
top, mid = ans.split(split_middle)
start, columns = top.split(split_top)

columns = re.sub('(\w)+', '\\\\textbf{\g<0>}', columns)

result = split_middle.join([split_top.join([start, columns]), mid])
>>> result
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\toprule
{} &       \textbf{name} &    \textbf{mask} &    \textbf{weapon} \\
\midrule
\textbf{0} &    Raphael &     red &       sai \\
\textbf{1} &  Donatello &  purple &  bo staff \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

In the output you can see, that the header now is bold.

Answer (score 1):

The answers given here are somewhat unnecessary. You can use the `pandas.Styler` implementation.

```py
styler = df.style
styler.applymap_index(lambda v: "font-weight: bold;", axis="index")
styler.applymap_index(lambda v: "font-weight: bold;", axis="columns")
styler.to_latex(convert_css=True)
```

The documentation for `Styler.to_latex` gives alternative ways if you want to customise the LaTeX bold function, e.g. using `\textbf{}` instead of `\bfseries` for example.

The Styler implementation is ultimatelty intended to replace the older and less flexible `DataFrame.LatexFormatter`

Answer (score 0):

Based on mosc9575's intuition to manipulate output of `df.to_latex`, you can make column header is wrapped with some unique delimiters to make the substitution easier.

```py
import re

s = re.sub('<([^>]*)>', '\\\\textbf{\g<1>}',
           df.rename(columns=lambda x: f'<{x}>').to_latex(index=False))
```

```
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\toprule
   \textbf{name} & \textbf{mask} & \textbf{weapon} \\
\midrule
  Raphael &    red &      sai \\
Donatello & purple & bo staff \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack but if you know the column names ahead of time you can save your table to a file and then update the file directly with a python script. In your latex project you can use the `input{<filepath>}` command to import the saved file.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(...)
df.to_latex(latex_filepath)

with open(latex_filepath, "r") as fr:
    txt = fr.read()
make_bold_strs = (
    "column-name-1",
    "column-name-2",
    ...
)
for s in make_bold_strs:
    txt = txt.replace(s, "\\textbf{" + s + "}")
with open(latex_filepath, "w") as fw:
    fw.write(txt)
```

Import the table saved to `latex_filepath` into your main latex file like: `\input{latex_filepath}`