# Spread table over two pages after \input command

Tags: latex, overleaf

I am trying to input a table in my overleaf document and let it spread over two pages with the longtblr command, but it keeps being cut at the end of the page. Is there a way to allow for the table to spread over two pages while still using \input{table} instead of pasting the table in the text?
My code is this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf, justification=justified, singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=period,name=FIGURE}
\usepackage[tablename=TABLE,labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,makecell}
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{changepage}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr} 
\begin{adjustwidth}{0cm}{0cm}
\scalebox{0.8}{\input{aaa}}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{longtblr}


\end{document}
```

And the table looks as follows:

```
{
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{tabular}{l*{7}{c}}
\hline\hline
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(7)}\\
            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Country 1}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Country 2}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Country 3}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Country 4}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Country 5}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack{Rich}}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{\shortstack{Poor}}\\
\hline
main        &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     &                     \\
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
Xvar     &       0.521         &       0.132         &       1.100\sym{***}&       1.048\sym{*}  &       0.935\sym{***}&       0.100         &       0.888\sym{*}  \\
            &    (0.0377)         &    (0.244)         &    (0.0234)         &    (0.0256)         &    (0.5675)         &    (0.6345)         &    (0.0251)         \\
[1em]
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{8}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.10\), \sym{**} \(p<0.05\), \sym{***} \(p<0.01\)}\\
\end{tabular}
}
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You are using the `longtblr` environment from the tabularray package, but you are not loading this package. You can't use arbitrary macros inside the `longtblr`, have a look into the package documentation for `expand`. If you warp your table in scaleboxes and adjustboxes, it can't be broken across packages. The content of your `aaa.tex` file isn't the proper syntax for a `longtblr` body. A `longtblr` is basically a replacement for a `tabular` environment, not a wrapper around it.

Comment: Also the rest of the syntax is not compatible with the current version of the `tabularray` package. You need to replace all the (mostly unnecessary) `\multicolumn` etc. with their equivalents from tabularray

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response. This is how stata automatically creates the table, so if at all possible I would rather not edit the original table format as there are many of these tables and automatising it would be much faster. Given the table is not compatible with the current version, is there a way to edit the first code where I input the table so it spread over two pages?

Answer (score 1):

All these unnecessary and debilitating `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}` make this an unnecessarily hard task. I'd wish these automatic table generators would finally stop inserting them into their code.

If you use (at your own risk) an old version of the `tabularray` package, you can use the same trick as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/71473887/2777074 to make the `tabular` environment from your `aaa.tex` file like a `longtblr` environment.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf, justification=justified, singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=period,name=FIGURE}
\usepackage[tablename=TABLE,labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,makecell}
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{changepage}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}[=v2021]

\begin{document}

{%
  \renewenvironment{tabular}[2][c]{%
    \footnotesize%
    \begin{longtblr}{%
      colspec={@{}#2@{}}%
    }
  }{%
    \end{longtblr}%
  }%
  \input{aaa}%
}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much again for the reply. Indeed, it seems like this option will mess up other tables I have in the document so I would rather use the most up to date version of that package. Is this the best option you know or how would you do it if the table that you have is as the one I pasted above? I am open to pasting it in the text and editing it if that is better but had assumed there was a way to avoid doing that.

Comment: You can make the redefinition locally within a group `{...}` to not mess up other tables